# Have you ever used these css properties?

Tags: css, xhtml, cross-browser

In what cases these are useful?

```
table-layout
font-stretch
font-size-adjust
orphans and widows
marks
clip
```

Answer (score 2):

orphans and widows are used commonly in print to avoid a single line at the bottom or top of a page.

More info can be found here just do a quick search
http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_tab_table-layout.asp

Answer (score 1):

I use `table-layout: fixed` a fair amount, but the others not so much. I've found that table-layout: fixed, along with `<col>` tags will speed up the rendering of a page with a very large table because the browser doesn't need to process the contents of all data in the table to calculate column sizes. It is also useful to have two tables with columns that align perfectly.

Clip looks like it could be useful, but I haven't used it before. A good article on clip is here:
http://www.ibloomstudios.com/articles/misunderstood_css_clip/

Orphans, widows, and marks are useful in print stylesheets I believe.  And the font ones are for scaling height/width of fonts. I'm not sure how supported any of those are, but `table-layout` is well supported.